# Filter results in HTML table by multiple filters in multiple filter categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, filter

I am developing an e-commerce website for a mobile phone seller where I receive a few results when searching a product. There is no way to control or filter the receiving results from the server side. So I need the ftering to be done on the client side through javascript or jquery.

So the requirement is to create a filter mechanism for the user to filter out the received results to show the required one.

In terms of filtering there are number of filter categories such as OS, screen size, Processor, RAM etc. Under each filter category there will be a set of options based on the results received.

Initially requirement was to select one option from a single filter category or from any number of filter categories. for example select o/s  android and screen size 5.5. SO all the matching results will be shown while hiding the rest.

I did this by populating data-* attributes on the table row with appropriate data. for example a result row of Nexus 6p would have data-os="android" data-scree-size="5.5" etc. and showing only the ones where this is matched.

```
$('table tr').hide();

$('table tr[data-os="' + appliedFilterOs+ '"][data-screen-size="' + appliedFilterScrSize+ '"]').show();
```

However now the requirement has changed so the user should be able to filter by multiple options in multiple categories. For example filter by O/S = Android or Windows and Screen size = 5.5 or 5.7 or 4.8

So with this its gets complicated and I would appreciate if any one can suggest a good algorithm to do this and show/hide results efficiently.

Comment: How many results are we talking about? 1000, 100,000, 1,000,000?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you have tried?

Comment: result vary from 100 to 1000s